# Что делать если элемнт появляеться слишком низко HTML5, CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5

Я верстаю сайт по теме информационной безопасности на html и css и хочу разделить информацию линией. Линию я смог сделать но она как-то криво появляется...

```css
* {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #1F1230;
    color: white;
}

.connection {
    background-color: #3e255e;
    height: 165px;
    width: 165px;
    border: 0.5px solid #fff; /* Белая рамка */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Радиус скругления */
}

.line {
    margin: 166px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RemotePC</title>
    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="theme-link">
    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="connection">
        <br \>
        <center><img src="images/lock.png"></center>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        window.onresize = function () 
        {
            window.resizeTo(1100, 625);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[ВОТ ПОЛНЫЙ КОД НА CodePen](https://codepen.io/dudha369/pen/QWqLRPz)
Кто может помогите пожалуйста!!!!!!

Comment: В каком смысле криво? Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: Я уже всё починил! Но все ровно спасибо что хотели помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поднять линию, задав элементу абсолютное позиционирование. Для этого необходимо задать position: relative тому элементу, относительно которого вы хотите расположить вашу линию.

Используя ваш код, добавьте:

```
.connection{
    position: relative;
}

.line{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Таким образом, линия поднимется на самый верх страницы. О том, как работают различные виды позиционирования, можно ознакомиться тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё сработало

Comment: если ответ Вам помог, нажмите на галочку слева)

Comment: Добрый вечер! Извиняюсь если надоедаю, но у меня возникла проблема... Линия не доходит до конца!!!!!!!!!!! Я хочу её сделать в 625 пикселей, а она делается только в += 400 пикселей... Помогите если не сложно(код обновил на CodePen) https://codepen.io/dudha369/pen/QWqLRPz

Comment: margin: 0 0 0 175px;